How to read stdout from subprocess safely in Python
Two choice quotes from the documentation:
On Popen.stdout:

Warning
Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

And on Popen.communicate:

Note
The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited.

Great!  Now what?
What I need is something to the effect of:
with popen(["command", "--arg=foo"]) as file:
    while True:
        (out, err) = file.communicate_one_line()
        if out is None and err is None: break
        [...]

And I have an implementation using selectors, but that seems far too complicated for a Python program.  Have I overlooked a simple library which lets me work with a long-running program without trying to capture everything in a single output blob before handling it?

You only get deadlocks if you're writing to its stdin and reading from stdout in the loop. If you're just reading, you don't have to do anything special.

Well that's probably true if I want to do blocking reads on just one output, but what if I want to read either stdout or stderr, whichever is available?

That's where selectors becomes useful.
